# Can't get dimensions of imageView background image in android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, drawingcache

I'd like to work with dimensions of imgHelpBelow imageView background image and not with the source of this image.

Here is imgHelpBelow imageView XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgHelpBelow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ImageView05"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgCaloriesBelow"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgCaloriesBelow"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_fill"
    android:src="@drawable/bar_fill" />
```

Here is the code:

```
private ImageView imgHelpBelow;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

          imgHelpBelow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgHelpBelow);

          imgHelpBelow.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

          imgHelpBelow.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
             MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
          imgHelpBelow.layout(0, 0, imgHelpBelow.getMeasuredWidth(),imgHelpBelow.getMeasuredHeight()); 


    imgHelpBelow.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgHelpBelow.getDrawingCache());
    imgHelpBelow.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing 

          int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

          Bitmap croppedBmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 120, h);
}
```

The width and the height I get are of the image source and not of the imageView background, where the dimensions should be greater, as a result the croppedBmp1 Bitmap is created from the image source and not from the imageview background. It seems like that all this procedure with DrawingCache didn't work.

The image is placed in res/drawable-xxhdpi. Maybe I should place the image in some other drawable folder.

What should I add or change?

Please help me...

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this usually has the same size as the imagesrc try to put fixed value ?

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: The bitmap I've created is from the imageView background, so the returned width and height should be of the imageView because the background image fills it.